# How to access a List View's custom formatter?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-rest-api, pnp-powershell, json-formatting

While doing some custom formatting for a List View, invalid JSON was checked-in and now, the List View will not render and I can't find a way to access the custom formatter without rendering the list and using "Format current view".

I'm aware of method using PnP but I don't have the permissions to execute it. Is there perhaps a way to glean the location from the PS script?

```
#Set the View Formatting
Set-PnPView -List $ListName -Identity $ViewName -Values @{CustomFormatter =$JSONFormat} -ErrorAction Stop
Write-host "View Format Applied Successfully!" -foregroundcolor Green
```

Source: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2021/03/sharepoint-online-format-list-view-using-powershell.html#ixzz7wcGLGUSM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the custom formatting applied on SharePoint list view using SharePoint REST API as well.

Use REST endpoint in below format:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ChildList')/views/getbytitle('All Items')?$select=Title,CustomFormatter
```

**Update**:

Refer below code example for updating JSON view formatting:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateViewJSONFormatting(listName, viewName) {
        var viewEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/views/getbytitle('" + viewName + "')";

        var jsonFormatting = {
            "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
            "additionalRowClass": "sp-field-severity--good"
        };
        
        var viewProperties = {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.View"
            },
            "CustomFormatter": JSON.stringify(jsonFormatting)
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: viewEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": "*"
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(viewProperties),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

You can call above function like:

```
updateViewJSONFormatting('Comments List', 'All Items')
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint Online: Apply JSON View formatting using SharePoint REST API](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/03/30/sharepoint-online-apply-json-view-formatting-using-sharepoint-rest-api/)

Comment: That works. And to POST the changes back is the same URL?

Comment: Check updated answer for POST